# Importing modules for testing

Tags: haskell, testing

I'm having some trouble importing a module for testing. I want to import `Load` in `TestLoad` in order to test it. I've tried adding the source directory to `hs-source-dirs` and both the package `nsga` and the module `Load` to `build-depends` in the cabal file for the testing package, but GHC still complains `Could not find module Load` when I attempt to `import Load` in `TestLoad.hs`.

I'm also curious about how to structure the tests and how to name the files. Is the approach below correct?

Directory structure:

```
nsga/
    src/
        Main.hs
        Load.hs
    test/
        TestMain.hs
        TestLoad.hs
```

The cabal file:

```
executable nsga
    main-is: Main.hs
    build-depends:
        QuickCheck -any,
        base -any,
        doctest -any
    default-language: Haskell2010
    hs-source-dirs: src
    other-modules:
        Load
    ghc-options: -ferror-spans -Wall -fsimpl-tick-factor=10

test-suite test-nsga
    type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is: TestMain.hs
    build-depends:
        QuickCheck -any,
        base -any,
        doctest -any,
        HUnit -any,
        nsga -any,
        Load -any
    default-language: Haskell2010
    hs-source-dirs: test, src
    other-modules:
        TestLoad
    ghc-options: -ferror-spans
```

Comment: I think you only need to add `exposed-modules:  Load` (not to `other-modules` - it will be hidden there) to `nsga` (usually you add a *lib* for this stuff though) - you should not need to add `src` to the `hs-source-dirs` of the testsuite at all.

Comment: If you want to see it *in action* I recommend grabbing `stack` and just try out one of the templates - for example `stack new LetsLook franklinchen` (this will use the `franklinchen` template that includes a *lib*, an *executable* using the lib and a *test-suite* testing the lib)

Comment: Adding `exposed-modules: Load` did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `Load -any` line from the `build-depends`.

`build-depends` refers to names of *packages*, but `Load.hs` is a *module*. Is there a package called `Load` installed on your system?

FWIW, this works for me:

File layout:

```
├── app
│   ├── Load.hs
│   └── Main.hs
├── src
│   └── Lib.hs
├── test
│   └── Spec.hs
└── test-load.cabal
```

test-load.cabal:

```
name:                test-load
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable the-app
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base

test-suite spec
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test, app
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base, Load -any
```

Run using:

```
cabal configure
cabal build
cabal test
```

Comment: If I just run `TestLoad.hs` in the command file, then the cabal file is ignored? I have to build an .exe first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the command file". If you run `ghc` or `ghci` yourself the cabal file is ignored. `cabal` uses the cabal file to figure out how to call `ghc` and `ghci`.

Comment: Sorry, meant command line, e.g. `ghci`. So I need to build the exe in order to run the test? It does compile now, however non of the tests are actually executed when running `cabal test` (example in /test/Main.hs: `i = TestCase (assertBool "mytest3" True)`)

Comment: Good - it seems we answered your original question. As for why your tests don't produce any output - that's technically a new question and you should open up a new SO question for that.